# No errors when updating mysql database but table is not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to update remote MySQL database, but table is not updating. PHP does not show any errors.

I am using this php code:

```
<?php

// php code to Update data from mysql database Table

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
   
   $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
   
   // get values form input text
   
   $headingSrb = $_POST['heading_srb'];
   $paragraphSrb = $_POST['paragraph_srb'];
   $headingEng = $_POST['heading_eng'];
   $paragraphEng = $_POST['paragraph_eng'];        
   // mysql query to Update data
   $query = "UPDATE `update_slide_1` SET `heading_ser`='".$headingSrb."',`paragraph_ser`='".$paragraphSrb."', `heading_eng`='".$headingEng."', `paragraph_eng`='".$paragraphEng."' ";      
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);      
   if($result)
   {
       echo '<p style="text-align: center; padding:5px; background-color: rgba(9, 143, 72, 0.6); color:white; ">Data Updated.</p> ';
       echo "$query";
   }else{
       echo '<p style="text-align: center; padding:5px; background-color: rgba(183, 0, 3, 0.7); color:white; ">Data Not Updated.</p> ';
   }

   mysqli_close($connect);

}


?>
```

I have entered "asd" in all form text imputs and Echo query shows that it is pulling data from my html form, so that is not a problem:

UPDATE `update_slide_1` SET `heading_ser`='asd',`paragraph_ser`='asd', `heading_eng`='asd', `paragraph_eng`='asd'

Maybe I did not set up the table or columns in my database.
Here is the picture of my database table:
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfStr.png)

Comment: the result echo 'Data Updated'?

Comment: Please learn how to use prepare stmt for prevent sql inject.

Comment: No `WHERE` clause ? All entries will be updated

Comment: Did you try to execute the request you print into PHPMyAdmin ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes I am getting Data Updated, but nothing happens in database.

Comment: where you take `mysqli_connect` variable?

Comment: Why would I need WHERE clause? I am updating 4 columns and there is only one row in it. @Cid

Comment: Because if when you will have more than 1 row, ALL of them will be updated. [`SQL_SAFE_UPDATES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) can prevent this too

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am using only one row so I left out "where" clause

Comment: What's the point of a table with a single row?

Comment: I have created a "Notification Board" where notifications will be updated every day. That Notification Board will read data from this table. I don't need any other rows for that, right? @Cid

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Like: why not check whether MySQL returns any error message?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure. Do you want to update existing records in your table or insert a new row?

If you want to update, check if the table has any record. Otherwise, it will return nothing. Also, you didn't add `where` so after running this request all the records in the table will be updated by this data.

If you want to insert a new record you should use `insert` request. For example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `update_slide_1` (`heading_ser`, `paragraph_ser`, `heading_eng`, `paragraph_eng`) VALUES ('".$headingSrb."', '".$paragraphSrb."', '".$headingEng."', '".$paragraphEng."')";
```

Comment: Oh wow, it looks like I did not have any records in my table. I totally missed that part because I have used that table before but i deleted all records later. Thank you!